# Getting Error while adding File System ISE Logic App Connector

Tags: filesystems, azure-logic-apps, connector

I have created an ISE Logic Apps environment, and am trying to add the FileSystem ISE connector to the Managed connectors list, as it does not appear in my default list. When I click on '+Add', I can see the File System connector in the drop down that comes up, but when I select it & click on 'Create', I get the following error:

Failed to create connector 'isefilesystem'

Operation name
Set Integration Service Environment managed API
Time stamp
Mon Jan 13 2020 16:53:24 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Event initiated by
xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx

Error code
IntergrationServiceEnvironmentManagedApiDefinitionTagsNotSupported
Message
The tags are not supported in the managed API 'isefilesystem'.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Comment: After a detailed analysis it was found that the error is because of a custom Tagging policy that is applied on the Azure subscription. Because of this policy every new resource automatically gets tagged with certain parameters. After raising a ticket with MSFT, I was told by the support person that ISE File System Connector does not support Tagging & advised me to disable the applied policy before adding the desired connector. I haven't tried this yet, but I wonder why the connector does not support tagging. Can MSFT please look into this? In my opinion every resource should support tagging.

Answer (score 1):

The ISE File System connector is available. The ISE File System connector will not be automatically added to the ISE, you will need to manually add it yourself. Our engineers are working on getting that automatically added with new ISE deployments.

Here are steps from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/add-artifacts-integration-service-environment-ise#add-ise-connectors) to add it manually to the ISE :

1. On your ISE menu, under Settings, select Managed connectors. On the toolbar, select **Add**.

[image]

2. On the Add a new managed connector pane, open the Find connector list. Select the ISE connector that you want to use but isn't yet deployed in your ISE. Select Create.

[image: Select the ISE connector that you want to deploy in your ISE]

Only ISE connectors that are eligible but not yet deployed to your ISE appear available for you to select. Connectors that are already deployed in your ISE appear unavailable for selection.

Checkout [this GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45210) issue as well for details.

Comment: Thanks Ketan. As mentioned in my reply to Joey above, I was told by MSFT support that ISE File System connector does not support tagging. When I try to add the connector, a custom tagging policy applied on the Azure subscription automatically tries to tag the resource & it fails because tagging is not supported by the connector. I want to request MSFT to make every resource 'tagable'.

Answer (score 0):

File system connectors is [not yet available in ISE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/208582f6-177e-4120-afb7-dce8b27bf543/can-the-file-system-connector-trigger-work-in-ise-eg-pick-up-a-new-file?forum=azurelogicapps). You can use the shared connector (With gateway) in a Logic app in ISE till it is available.

It is on-premises data gateway. Yes there is already a work items for this and it is in progress and will be there in near future but this timeline is subject to change. As far as new features go, we are not able to disclose much at this time.

Also you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/37961506-filesystem-connector-ise-support) to promote this feature to be achieved quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems with the ISE Create File (Preview).

I have an API Connection defined with the Root Folder setting using dot notation, e.g. 192.168.1.23, because there is a DNS issue with hybrid cloud-on-prem lookup, or so I am told.

The Logic App portal editor in Designer mode behaves strangely when configuring the folder path in the Create File action. When using the pop-out folder picker I see "The use name or password is incorrect".

I have made sure that the credentials are correct and have tested successfully via other means.

Is there a work around?
Is this a known issue?